# Using nested forEach loops to push and object to an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'd love an explanation as to why the result of this function don't match my expectation.

```
const numbers = [ 1, 2 ]
const objects = [{f: 'a'}, {f: 'b'}]

async function(domain) {
  let matrix = []
  objects.forEach((object) => {
    numbers.forEach((number) => {
      object.number = number
      matrix.push(object)
    })
  }) 
  return matrix
}()
```

### Actual

The result, once the promise is resolved returns:

```
[ 
  { f: 'a', number: 2 },
  { f: 'a', number: 2 },
  { f: 'b', number: 2 },
  { f: 'b', number: 2 } 
]
```

### Expected

But, my expectation is that it would return:

```
[ 
  { f: 'a', number: 1 },
  { f: 'a', number: 2 },
  { f: 'b', number: 1 },
  { f: 'b', number: 2 } 
]
```

One of the things that puzzles me the most is that if I `console.log` the value of object just before I push, it logs out each of the objects in my expected result.

Comment: Why do you define your function as `async` when there is nothing async happening in it, and you have no `await`?

Comment: Whoops. It's because I extracted the problem from another piece of code that does use await. I can remove that and rephrase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because objects are passed by reference and you are modifying original object, instead you can push new object.

```js
const numbers = [ 1, 2 ]
const objects = [{f: 'a'}, {f: 'b'}]

let matrix = []
objects.forEach((object) => {
  numbers.forEach((number) => {
    matrix.push({...object, number})
  })
})

console.log(matrix)
```

Comment: Its probably rest syntax in object try this instead `matrix.push(Object.assign({}, object, {number}))`

Comment: @HermanLauenstein Probably object spread is not implemented yet. Use `Object.assign()` then `matrix.push(Object.assign({}, object, {number}))`

Comment: To me, it doesn't matter as my target environment is Node with some transpilation. Should I tag my question with something to make that apparent? I kinda figured it would all fall under the ES6 tag.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to iterate the `objects`, with a nested [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the `numbers` and return an array of new objects with the relevant number. The flatMap will flatten the arrays produced by the map to a single array:

```js
const numbers = [ 1, 2 ]
const objects = [{f: 'a'}, {f: 'b'}]

const matrix = objects.flatMap(o => // map the objects and flatten
  numbers.map( // map the numbers
    number => ({ ...o, number }) // return a new object with the number
  )
);

console.log(matrix);
```

**Old answer:**

Use nested [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the `objects` and the `numbers`, and [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create new objects that include the relevant number. Flatten resulting nested arrays by using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=b):

```js
const numbers = [ 1, 2 ]
const objects = [{f: 'a'}, {f: 'b'}]

const matrix = [].concat(... // flatten the nested arrays
  objects.map((o) => // map the objects
    numbers.map( // map the numbers
      (number) => Object.assign({}, o, { number }) // return a new object with the number
    )
  ));

console.log(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Nenad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4620771/nenad-vracar) is correct. You can also do it with **reduce** and **map**.

```js
const numbers = [ 1, 2 ];
const objects = [{f: 'a'}, {f: 'b'}];

const matrix = numbers.reduce((acc, nxt) => {
 const numberedObjs = objects.map(obj => ({...obj, number:nxt}));
 acc.push(...numberedObjs);
 return acc;
}, []);
```